# Cannot read property 'find' of inherited method in unit tests

Tags: mongodb, typescript, unit-testing, nestjs, typeorm

im having an issue trying to run an e2e test for my NestJS application tha uses a mongodb-memory-server to run mongo in memory

my e2e test looks like this

```
describe('UsersController.e2e', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let module: TestingModule;
  const mongod = new MongoMemoryServer();

  beforeAll(async () => {

    const port = await mongod.getPort();
    const database = await mongod.getDbName();

    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [UserRepository, UserService],
      controllers: [UserController],
      imports: [TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
        useFactory: () => {
          return {
            type: 'mongodb',
            host: '127.0.0.1',
            port,
            database,
            entities: [__dirname + '../../../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
          } as TypeOrmModuleOptions;
        },
      }),
        TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])
      ]
    }).compile();

    app = module.createNestApplication();

    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await module.close();
    await app.close();
  });

  describe('GET /users', () => {
    it('should return a collection of user resources', async () => {

      const { body } = await supertest
        .agent(app.getHttpServer())
        .get('/users')
        .set('Accept', 'application/json')
        .expect('Content-Type', /json/)
        .expect(200);
      expect(body).toEqual(userCollectionMock);
    });
  });
});
```

when running the test it throws a 500 error

```
Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined
    at UserRepository.Object.<anonymous>.MongoRepository.find (src/repository/MongoRepository.ts:77:29)
    at UserRepository.index (src/modules/user/repositories/user.repository.ts:12:20)
```

the repository class looks like

```
export class UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User> implements IResourceRepository<User> {

  index(): Promise<User[]> {
    return this.find();
  }
}
```

the extension of MongoRepository provides find() https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/src/repository/MongoRepository.ts#L76

So it perplexes me as to why it is undefined!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a month old, but I just ran into this issue and resolved it.

I'm using mongoose + typegoose with mongodb-memory-server.

```
import { MongoMemoryServer } from 'mongodb-memory-server';

describe('Auth', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;
  let mongoServer: MongoMemoryServer;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    // Set up database
    mongoServer = new MongoMemoryServer();
    const mongoUri = await mongoServer.getUri();

    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ...
        TypegooseModule.forRoot(mongoUri, {
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
        }),
        ...
      ],
      controllers: [...],
      providers: [...],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await mongoServer.stop();
  });
});
```

The main mistake I was making was that I had separately overwritten my User Typegoose injection.

```
  providers: [
    // THIS WAS MY MISTAKE!
    {
      provide: getModelToken('User'),
      useValue: mockUserModel,
    },
  ],
```

I know this is not a complete answer to your question, but I hope this might help you.